# Are my MacBook Pro 2015 (15-inch) fan parameters correct?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

Are the fans on MacBook Pro 15inch always on? If so should they be audible when ear against keyboard?

I am not sure but I think my fans were not audible before but now I can hear them if I put my ear there.

Using istats menu I can see them running at ~2100 rpm left fan, ~2000 right fan.

The computer temperature is between 35-45 degrees celsius.

All I am asking are the temperatures, fan speed and subtle noise normal?

Answer (score 1):

Fans, which contain moving parts, will certainly make some audible noise, though it's usually rather quiet and unnoticeable. Normal speeds should range from 1800-2200 depending on your level of usage. Intensive processes see the fan speeds go up to 6200.

For temperatures, idle activity should have temperatures at 40-50 ºC (CPU PECI die) and 30 ºC for air flow proximity.

If your fans get really loud and noisy, it may be a sign that your fans are malfunctioning **or** there could be some form of obstruction that causes noise when air runs over it. I'd check for dust and clean out any foreign objects found.

Comment: the thing is, about the noise i notice, is that the left fan noise i hear the normal noise of a fan pushing air, but on the right side, its more like a refrigerator kind of noise. is that normal? Also the noise on the right side, is audible without me putting my ear against the keyboard, being in a quiet place is enough.

Comment: Loud, noisy fans at 2000rpm that sounds like a refrigerator are almost certainly not normal. I can barely hear my fan even in a completely silent location, so it's probably best to take it in to Apple for checks. How old is your computer?

Comment: Guess i will..its not loud but definitely different sound from left fan... Its like 8 months old...